# Is there a rosnetwork? Or similar?

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What do I use to connect to a network socket in ROS, from which to get my robots data and then build publishers off?

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32395/is-there-a-rosnetwork?-or-similar?/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ros already provides a network transparent communication protocol based on sockets. Normally, you write nodes that directly communicate with the Robot's hardware and publish the data directly via topics.

If your robot data is provided on a socket, I suggest to create a ROS node that uses whatever you are used to, e.g. libc's socket functions, to communicate with your robot. Your ros node then needs to decode the data from the socket, put it into a ros message and publish it. I don't know about any generic way for implementing such a bridge since it is highly specific for your socket based protocol and the ros messages to be published.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Samuel Anudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/4849/samuel-anudeep/) on 2013-10-30**:
Correct me if I'm wrong, but ROS uses TCP underneath right? In that case, wouldn't there be a chance of a port clash?